# exiting a Python function call

Tags: python, if-statement, exit

How can my program exit a function call? I have a recursive function that, when a condition is satisfied, calls itself.

```
def function( arg ):
    if (condition):
        ...
        return function( arg + 1 )
```

My guess at how it works: if the condition is not satisfied, the function call will terminate. In my program, that doesn't seem to be the case -- the condition is violated but the program jumps to the return statement (perhaps the only return statement it sees?).

Is there some sort of exit() that I could put in an else clause?

Comment: Can you post the entire script instead of pseudo code?  It's hard to tell what is going wrong in your recursive calls without the full function and any related code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As listed, your code will always just return `None`. It goes through all the recursion, and does this until the condition is not met, and then drops out the end of the function and returns `None`.

For example, try this:

```
def f(x):
    if (x<10):
        return f(x+1)
    return x
```

and build up from this to do something useful.

Answer (score 0):

A "function terminating" results in it returning `None`. If you are seeing something different then it may very well be hitting the `return` you see, because it may be mis-indented. Use `python -tt myscript.py` to verify that you haven't mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: I think he meant to indent it there - "I have a recursive function that, when a condition is satisfied, calls itself."

Comment: @Tom: Sure, but if you've mixed tabs and spaces inappropriately then it can *appear* correct visually, but will be interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Why did you say it's mis-indented?

Comment: @Tom: I prefaced it with an "if".

Comment: Your grammar didn't indicate that. Fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

If a Python function does not explicitly `return` a value, it returns `None`. That implicit `return None` is analagous to `return` in C like languages.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the question.

Comment: He is asking *how* to exit a function call because his current code doesn't exit the function where he expects it to.  Return values don't really play a role in resolving the problem.

Comment: @chown OP thinks that function will jump to "the only return statement it sees". It won't. It will `return None` if the condition is not satisfied.